# Relationship between kernel CIFS driver and Samba project

Tags: linux, samba, cifs

If Samba is a collection of user-mode tools to access CIFS, but the kernel itself already contains a CIFS driver... how are these two things related? Did the kernel code originate from the Samba project? Is Samba itself depracated now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Samba project implements the *server* side of CIFS-related protocols:

- file and print services
- authentication and authorisation
- name resolution
- service announcement

See [Samba: An Introduction](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/SambaIntro.html) for details.

The Samba project provides `smbclient`, which is an `ftp`-style client for CIFS, but it doesn’t (currently) provide a client file system implementation. It also hosts [`cifs-utils`](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS_utils) which the kernel file system relies on. The in-kernel driver was developed and is maintained by Steve French, who is a long-standing member of the Samba project (and also currently employed by Microsoft).